# Vue2. Удаление конкретного элемента из массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой удаления элемента в массиве. Дело в том, что мой splice, удаляет всегда последний элемент в массиве. Пробовал перебирать массив и потом удаление, эффект такой-же. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылка на песочницу: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-snowflake-lhc1t?file=/src/App.vue

Метод `RemoveField(index) {this.fields.splice(index, 1)}` не удаляет выбранный элемент, удаляет всегда последний элемент массива.

Я кинул весь компонент, т.к. еще очень зеленый, возможно это даст полную картину, где я мог чудануть(

Comment: _«ссылка на песочницу: ...»_ - ссылка на ответ: [https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html). Если хочешь более точный ответ, то следует более точно задавать вoпрос: указывать относящийся к проблеме участок кода (а не ссылки на проект/сайт/чтоугодно), и конкретнее описывать возникшие затруднения. Отредактировать вoпрос можно нажатием текстовой кнопки "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1319920/edit)" под ним.

Comment: Где выполняется вызов метода, откуда берется значение передаваемое ему аргументом `index`, что из себя представляет объект `fields`? Эта информация все еще находится где-то по ссылке на посторонний ресурс. Ссылки и ресурсы имеют свойство помирать через некоторое время, и контент по ним может меняться - поэтому, **код (минимальный, только часть относящаяся к проблеме) должен содержаться текстом прямо в вoпросе**, чтобы вoпрос впоследствии не стал бесполезным для других участников.

Comment: Без полной информации о проблеме, могу только посоветовать передавать аргументом само значение - а его индекс получать уже в методе (перед вызовом `splice`). Так будет надежнее, но не факт что это решит проблему (мог бы дать точный ответ, но подробностей нужных для этого - так и не дождался в вoпросе).

Comment: В key надо передать не индекс, а id

Answer (score 1):

в приведенном коде @click="RemoveField(index) , и что тут должно удалиться? переменная index будет иметь всегда 0. Она не определена. Тут либо реактивная переменная должна быть, либо значение какого-то поля

чтобы подсказывать что-то, надо понять. Что удалять? Список языков или уровень языка?

```
        <select v-model="selectedSkill[index]">
          <option v-for="(item, index) in skillOptions" :key="item.text">
            {{ skillOptions[index].text }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-2 mb-1 pl-0">
        <button variant="secondary" class="" @click="RemoveField(index)">
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
```

index в v-for никак не попадет в RemoveField(index)
и надо понимать, что индексы в массиве источнике ну никак не транслируются в select. Там просто значения и все.

тут просто надо @click="RemoveField"

- достаточно переменной, чтобы сохранять значение текста. Можно и value, смотря какая логика

```
<select v-model="selectedSkill">
```

а в методе удаления ищем в массиве индекс элемента по текстовому совпадению и только тогда удаляем

```
    RemoveField() {
      const index = this.skillOptions.findIndex((item)=>{return (item.text===this.selectedSkill)} ) 
       if (index > -1) {
         this.skillOptions.splice(index, 1)
       }
    }
}
```

такой код будет удалять выбранные элементы в селекте скилов. поскольку общей задачи не понимаю, как-то так.